# Convention for **the** angle between two lines? Acute or obtuse?

Tags: geometry

Two lines that intersect in the plane form two angles: one acute (between $0$ and $\pi/2$, inclusive) and another obtuse (between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$, inclusive).

When we speak of "**the** angle between two lines", is there a standard convention for which of the above two we're referring to?

---

I think it is (or "should" be) the acute angle, but can't seem to find any definitive reference for this.

So far the closest I've found is [this passing remark](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1991153/986614) by Camille:

> Where I'm from, the convention for angles between two undirected lines refers to the acute angle between them.

Comment: In general the angle between two lines is $\alpha\in[0,\pi)$

Comment: Acute means between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

Comment: It's fair to establish a convention that we choose the angle $[0, \tfrac{\pi}{2}]$ by default, but it would be best to name that convention in whatever context you're working with these angles.

Comment: @markvs: Oops thanks correected

Comment: When we have a line in a Cartesian plane with $x,y$ coordinates, we often speak of the angle the line makes with the $x$ axis, and we don't mean for this angle value to be the same for the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$. That's not exactly an "angle between two lines" but I think it is close enough to cause confusion if you're not careful.

Comment: There is no one preferred angle between two intersecting lines. Two such lines form two angles which sum up to $\pi$. Otherwise it would be hard to define obtuse (acute) triangles.

Comment: @markvs: Don't three points define any triangle?

Comment: Although it is more of an English convention than a mathematical one, when someone says "the thing" but there are multiple things, it means "the thing that is relevant to the conversation".

Comment: @user24096:I was writing about obtuse (acute) triangles. But also internal (external) angles of a triangle are angles between lines containing its sides (two for each vertex).

Comment: For what it's worth, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4253451/finding-a-straight-line-that-makes-a-given-angle-with-a-given-straight-line/4253493?r=SearchResults&s=2|75.4985#4253493) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113258/choosing-normals-for-non-orientable-surfaces/4113434?r=SearchResults&s=3|71.3843#4113434) is my position on the matter.

Comment: @DavidK To be fair, in the context of "the angle that $y=-x$ makes with the $x$-axis", the $x$-axis is being considered a directed line, so this example is actually closer to 'angle between vectors' than to 'angle between lines', and thus the answer is understood to be $135º$ rather than acute.

Comment: @ryang There is some kind of directionality implied, yes, but it's implicit. That's the potentially confusing part. On the other hand, looking at the [original problem statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4253451/139123) for your first example, it says "the equation of the straight line", which is a strange way to say "the two equations of the two straight lines" that satisfy the other conditions of the problem.

Comment: I think I've sometimes seen "the acute angle between two lines", which seems like a good way to disambiguate the statement at the cost of just one extra word (although if a right angle is a possibility I might try "non-obtuse" even though it sounds clumsier than "acute").

Answer (score 1):

It's more common to speak of *the* angle between two *vectors* by using, for instance, the dot product formula:
$$
\cos \theta 
= \frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}}{\lvert\vec{v}\rvert \, \lvert\vec{w}\rvert}.
$$
Of course, every vector generates a line by taking its span (all possible scaled copies of it)
$$
\operatorname{span} \{\vec{v}\} = \{ c\vec{v} \mid c \in \Bbb{R} \}, 
$$
but we lose the direction information that the vector had:
$$
\operatorname{span} \{-\vec{v}\} = \operatorname{span} \{\vec{v}\}
$$

As the dot product formula shows, if you negate either of the vectors, the cosine is negated, so the supplementary angle $\pi - \theta$ gives *the* angle between them.

Comment: The question was about angles between two lines. It goes back to at least Euclid. You are saying that it is better to ask a different question. Note that there are very many different dot products even in $\mathbb R^2$.